# A faster thread blocks slower thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, performance

I'm working on a point cloud viewer, and my design is based on two thread

- first thread updates the point cloud data ( about 10 fps)
- second thread is a D3D renderer to render the point set to screen (about 90 fps)

so my code looks like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<PointCloud> pointcloud;
CRITICAL_SECTION updateLock;
void FirstThreadProc()
{
      while(true)
      {
       /* some algorithm processes point cloud, takes time */
            EnterCriticalSection(&updateLock);
            pointcloud->Update(data,length,...); //also takes time to copy and process
            LeaveCriticalSection(&updateLock);
      }
}
/*...*/  
std::shared_ptr<D3DRenderer> renderer;
void SecondThreadProc()
{
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else
        {
            EnterCriticalSection(&updateLock);
            renderer->Render(pointcloud);
            LeaveCriticalSection(&updateLock);
        }
    } 
}
```

I was thought that the second thread is way more fast than first one, so when first one entered the critical section, the second one is blocked, so the renderer window should freeze now or then. but what i'm observed right now is that the renderer window runs very smooth, camera rotate or zoom in/out, all good, but the first thread is very unstable, its fps is ranging from 10 fps to 1 fps.

I'm thinking about two point cloud buffers, then first thread updates the second buffer when outsides the critical section, then swap two buffers within critical section. Will it work?

Comment: What went wrong when you tried?

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't get it...

Comment: Your question is "Will it work?" My question in return is why you have reason to believe that it won't.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a hypothetical problem that never actually existed.

Comment: ... although for reference: yes, double-buffering (or even triple-buffering) like this is perfectly normal and many people use it successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx), CRITICAL_SECTION is not provide first-in, first-out(FIFO) ordering. since the second thread is way more fast than the first thread, and its whole loop is critical section, it will enter the critical section right after leave it. This may always in  the critical section and keep the first one out of it.

my solution is to put more job of the second thread outside the critical section, then it works fine.